# Issue displaying individual JSON data value

Tags: jquery, json

In my php file I have

```
$data = array();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, true))   
{$data[] = $row;};  
echo json_encode($data);
```

It produces the JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "record_id": "4",
        "eq_type_id": "999",
        "scidiv_id_tag": "AKINS04",
        "date_last_updated": "2011-07-11 14:41:58",
        "description": "Optics Table D",
        "eq_type_desc": "Other Equipment Type"
    }
]
```

In my JQUERY script:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    //dataType: "json",
    url: "../scidiv/php/editData.php",
    data: "recid=" + scidivtag,
    success: function(data)
    {
       $('#output1').html(data);
       $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+ data[0].record_id + "<b> name: </b>" +data[1].eq_type_id); 
     }
```

});

```
$('#output1').html(data); displays the above array on my web page....
```

But both

```
$('#output').html("Record Id: "+ data.record_id+"Eq Type ID: "+ data.eq_type_id);
```

an

```
$('#output').html("Record Id: "+ data[0].record_id+"Eq Type ID: "+ data[1].eq_type_id);
```

Gives me

> id: undefined name: undefined

Can someone tell me what I'm missing??

Thanks
Chris

Comment: If it displays the above array on the webpage your data didn't get encoded properly (you just got text). How are you retrieving the data object?

Comment: I'm using $.ajax() to execute the PHP file and return the JSON array

Comment: Did you set the datatype properly? If the server doesn't return application/json jQuery will probably use text/html.

Comment: I did not set the dataType.  What should I set it to?? It does not work when I add dataType: json to my JQUERY script

Comment: *dataType : 'json'* should work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the assistance and suggestions...

I solved the problem by re-writing my php script from scratch...
The main thing I did was get the results of the query as a simple array since I'm getting only one row of data the query:

```
$jqdata = mysql_fetch_row($result,);   
echo json_encode($jqdata);
```

So my json looks like:

```
["7","1","999","AKINS01","2011-07-11 14:39:22","Optics Table A","Other Equipment Type"]
```

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing in Firefox or Chrome by any chance (IE sucks)?  If so, use console.log to output the data coming back from the server side.  It may be that jQuery isn't interpreting your response as JSON and therefore not parsing it.  What is the response content type that is supplied?  Make sure it is application/json.  Either that, or you can force jQuery to parse it as JSON by setting the dataType to "json" for the AJAX request.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax.

Comment: What I am getting at is it being returned from jquery as a string or an array?

Comment: Ahh.... I thought the echo json_encode($data) in the PHP script returns an array to the success function of the JQUERY.... I am wrong in thinking so??

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the square braces wrapping it. You have an "array" with only one member (a map).

Without the square braces, data.eqType_id should work fine.

With the braces there, you always have to first look into member 0 of the array: data[0].eqType_id for example. But the extra level of nesting adds a layer that isn't necessary unless you are going to actually pass an array of maps.

Comment: The JSON array is being created by {$data[] = $row;};  
 and echo json_encode($data); and I don't know how to remove the square braces... Also, I also did the data[0] and still got the undefined result

Comment: It sounds that the var 'data' in you js contains the string of json, instead of the correct data decoded from that string. Otherwise, I believe you can't simply use $.html() to show an array.

Comment: Any idea how I can check/test if it is passing a string instead of an array?

Comment: I've been operating under the assumption you're using .ajax() or a similar JavaScript AJAX function to retrieve the data. This being the case, if you use Firefox with Firebug, you will see in the response a tab for "JSON" data if it's returned correctly.

Comment: I've updated my question with the JQUERY script.  I am using the .ajax() function...

Comment: There's some sort of information missing, because that JSON is accessible by data[0].keyname. The data[0] never changes because you're nesting into an array with only 1 member. It will always be a zero in there. So either you're misunderstanding and putting data[1], data[2] (etc), the JS engine is not interpreting it as JSON or the sample provided isn't exactly what the server is showing. Load Firefox, fire up Firebug, and inspect the GET request. Uncomment your dataType parameter just to be explicit, as well.